# How to remove remaining text in a string after a certain number of forward slashes?

Tags: python

I am trying to remove the rest of the string after a certain number of forward slashes. 
I want this:

```
https://yeezysupply.com/17655971/checkouts/4cba9aacf4ad07b281d152fb4b51c8cc/stock_problems
```

To become this:

```
https://yeezysupply.com/17655971/checkouts/4cba9aacf4ad07b281d152fb4b51c8cc
```

I want to remove the text after the 6th forward slash.

Comment: What did you tried so far? Do you know about [regex](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html)?

Comment: I heard about regex, but have no clue on how to use it @olinox14

Comment: Well, you're supposed to show some code you tried to write, and people here will help you to find out what is not working... See: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A good start here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using splitting and join:

```
u = "https://yeezysupply.com/17655971/checkouts/4cba9aacf4ad07b281d152fb4b51c8cc/stock_problems"
u = "/".join(u.split("/")[:6])
```

It separates your url by the `/` character and joins the first 6 back with the same character

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to split the string on `/`, then join back the first 6 parts. Alternatively, you could use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html):

```
import re

s = 'https://yeezysupply.com/17655971/checkouts/4cba9aacf4ad07b281d152fb4b51c8cc/stock_problems'
s = re.sub(r'((.*?/){6}).*', r'\1', s)
```

For more serious URL manipulation it's better to use something like [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html), of course.